# Set uncommitted read as default in Oracle SQL Developer with DB2 database

Tags: db2, oracle-sql-developer

I am using SQL Developer with a IBM DB2 database. I am only querying the data for analytical purposes - never making any updates, additions or deletions. I was wondering if there is a way to ensure that every query is an uncommitted read by default so that I never lock the tables. Is there a way that I can do this without typing `FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR` at the end of every query? Would enabling the settings for `Autocommit` in `Preferences -> Database -> Advanced` achieve the same goal (not lock tables)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Firstly, you can simply run the statement

```
SET CURRENT ISOLATION UR
```

in your session before executing other statements.

Alternatively, you can set a property in the JDBC URL you use to connect to the database, like so:

```
jdbc:db2://host:port/database:defaultIsolationLevel=1;
```

The value `1` corresponds to the constant `java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` (note that it is implementation-dependent and may break).